# Registration user using firebase throug email and password?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, registration

I created register activity with Firebase Authorization, and trying to register new user, but when I press register button I got exception from my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmailRegiter);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPasswordRegiter);
    etPasswordRe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPasswordRegiterRe);

    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

    passwordRule = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.password_rule);

    etPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            passwordRule.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createAccount(etUsername.getText().toString(), etPassword.getText().toString());
        }
    });

}

private void createAccount(String email, String password) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "createAccount:" + email);
//        if (!validateForm()) {
//            return;
//        }

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, ":" + mDatabase.child(PATH_TO_DATA_USERS));

//                            sendEmailVerification();
//                            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
//                            intent.putExtra("user", user.getUid());
//                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                         else {
                            try {
                                throw task.getException();
                            } catch(FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException e) {
                                etPassword.setError("weak password");
                                etPassword.requestFocus();
                            } catch(FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                                etEmail.setError("invalid credential exception");
                                etEmail.requestFocus();
                            } catch(FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
                                etEmail.setError("collision exception");
                                etEmail.requestFocus();
                            } catch(Exception e) {
                                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                            }
                            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, ":" + (mAuth == null));
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
```

xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etUserName"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_user_name"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEmailRegiter"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPasswordRegiter"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPasswordRegiterRe"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password_re"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/password_rule"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/password_rule"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="17sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/button_register"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

(Here in my code task.isSuccessful() returns me false and for to solve this problem i commented my validation method. So now no validation for password and email, but before I tried to run code with validation, which returns me same error)

and in logs get error like this

```
E/Volley: [187] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=AIzaSyAPBVdM4hZpPBvTZrvE9gBjld0otb202Lg
I/AuthChimeraService: Error description received from server: {
  "error": {
   "errors": [
    {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "invalid",
     "message": "INVALID_EMAIL"
    }
   ],
   "code": 400,
   "message": "INVALID_EMAIL"
  }
 }
```

By the way I tried to sign up by creation new user by myself through console. It works well I can sign with this user.

Here is my gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
```

Comment: Have you tried putting in another email?

Comment: Yes, but in did not help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the email user put in is not valid. Emails should be in this format = `"myname@domain.com"`. If it does not match the format, that error is given by the server. Try putting in an email in that format. I will recommend you to read more about authentication here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler and here is a bit more about the firebase error codes: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth

**EDIT:**
You are sending **"Username"** to the email variable not the **"Email"** 
Here is the code you need to fix: 
`createAccount(etUsername.getText().toString(), etPassword.getText().toString());`
You are sending username in the place of email so thats why the server is calling your email invalid. Change it to `etEmail`. 
**Remember, when you are registering, you are registering with the Email not the Username!**

Comment: Actually I tried to register my email and gmail address, but in both cases i got same error

Comment: @AssetBekbossynov Check for extra spaces and format of your email while you write it and please put your firebase auth code in your question

Comment: I tried to register 10 times my email, I think I write right email one time at least)))

Comment: @AssetBekbossynov Can you please include your code in the question? (Use edit to put in code again) and your xml too

Comment: Which code you need. I included my method for creating user into my answer.

Comment: @AssetBekbossynov Can you log on the exceptions and then tell me the result? Also log the email on exception

Comment: 'email is: example@gmail.com'

Comment: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The email address is badly formatted.
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbix.zzcb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbiu$zzj.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbjf.zzcc(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbjf$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbja$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact

Comment: Can you put your xml code and the initialization of your edittexts and buttons

Comment: @AssetBekbossynov No problem :)

Answer (score -2):

I'm starting using Firebase too, I'm using this code to register new users in my app and works well.

```
public void doRegister(final String username, String password) {

    HideAppApplication.mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(activity, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d("LOGIN", "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        User user = new User();
                        user.setUserId(username);
                        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");
                        mDatabase.child(task.getResult().getUser().getUid()).setValue(user);
                    }

                    onRegisterRequested.registerRequested(task);
                }
            });
}
```

You can take a look to my project in [github](https://github.com/JuanGarciaLucena/HideApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/emebesoft/hideapp/registerView) if you want.

Hope this can solve your problem.