# I am trying to connect firebase to my android application with sign in method in firebase authentication but not able to register with an error

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-authentication

Everytime I try to register with an email and password, I fail to register and the firebase is not updated.
Here's my code -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

private Button buttonRegsiter;
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    System.out.print("In main");
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    buttonRegsiter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerUserButton);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextpassword);

    buttonRegsiter.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void registerUser(){
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        //email field is empty
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        //password is empty
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter your password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    //if validations are ok
    //show a progressbar

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering user...");
    progressDialog.show();

    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task){
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed to register. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
              progressDialog.dismiss();
            }});
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == buttonRegsiter){
        registerUser();
    }
}
```

}

Error that I am getting in event log -
01-04 14:31:44.290 3734-3868/com.example.kinnari.trial E/FA: Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.NullPointerException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfj.zza(Unknown Source)
01-04 14:32:01.050 3734-3868/com.example.kinnari.trial E/FA: Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.NullPointerException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfj.zza(Unknown Source)
11:18 PM    Emulator: FramebufferData::restore: warning: a texture is deleted without unbinding FBO

11:18 PM    Emulator: FramebufferData::restore: warning: a texture is deleted without unbinding FBO

11:18 PM    Emulator: FramebufferData::restore: warning: a texture is deleted without unbinding FBO

Comment: Was any toast shown?

Comment: Post your app module `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Registration user using firebase throug email and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797431/registration-user-using-firebase-throug-email-and-password)

Comment: @BobSnyder Hey it worked now. I did not figure out the problem but when I tried running the app with a higher API it worked.

Comment: @aditya1508 No that is not the case.

Comment: @Ranjan yeah. It showed registration  failed. But when I tried with higher API emulator, it worked and reflected in firebase,